# NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'article' with keyword arguments '{'slug': ''}' not found

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-urls

The urls.py file created, containing the app_name = "articles" which is not recognized in the "template_base.html" established as model template.

```
NoReverseMatch at /articles/
Reverse for 'article' with keyword arguments '{'slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: \   ['articles/(?P\<slug\>\[-a-zA-Z0-9\_\]+)/\\Z'\]
```

The affected line is :

```
\<h2\>\<a href="{% url 'articles:article' slug=article.slug %}"\>{{ article.titre }}\</a\>\    </h2\>
```

3 times I try to perform the same code as in the lesson but I need your help.

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from articles import views

app_name = "articles"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.articles_view, name='articles'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.article_view, name='article')
]
```

template_base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block titre %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
        <ul style="list-style: none">
        <li style="display: inline-block; padding: 10px 20px;">
            <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Accueuil</a>
        </li>
        <li style="display: inline-block; padding: 10px 20px;">
            <a href="{% url 'articles:articles' %}">Articles</a>
        </li>
        <li style="display: inline-block; padding: 10px 20px;">
            <a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    {% block contenu %} {% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from articles.models import Article


def articles_view(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'articles/list.html', context={'articles': articles})


def article_view(request, slug):
    return HttpResponse("Page d'article")
```

articles/list.html

```html
{% extends 'template_base.html' %}

{% block titre %}Page d'articles{% endblock %}

{% block contenu %}

  <h1>Les articles</h1>

  {% for article in articles %}

    <h2><a href="{% url 'articles:article' slug=article.slug %}">{{ article.titre }}</a></h2>

    <p>{{ article.contenu }}</p>

    <span>{{ article.date_publication }}</span>

  {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

articles.detail.html

```html
    {% extends 'template_base.html' %}

    {% block titre %}Page d'articles{% endblock %}

    {% block contenu %}

      <h1>{{ article.titre }}</h1>
      <p>{{ article.contenu }}</p>
      <span>{{ article.date_publication }}</span>


    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is the issue in the `articles/list.html` template, can you add it to your question? Could you add the Article model too?

Comment: Sure! Just updated

Comment: If you remove url generation from the template and just _print out_ `article.slug` as `article.titre`, do you see slug values?

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try the following line, the error is the same, at the same place..
Should I replace "slug" by "titre" also?

    <h2><a href="{% url 'articles:article' slug=article.titre %}">{{ article.titre }}</a></h2>

Comment: I meant this `{{ article.slug }}, {{ article.titre }}`, remove `<a href` temporarily. To see what you have in `article.slug`.

Comment: the error message means that article.slug is empty for at least one entry or article  has no field 'slug'.

Comment: Ok looks like, for an unknown reason, the first slug has been deleted from SQLite Database...
That was the main issue, no more problems! Thank you very much for your lights and time!